# Session not working for EmployeeDepartmentID BUT works with EmployeeLevelID when using logical operators

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, session

I was wondering if I could get some help here. There are two important things: 1. EmployeeLevelID (CEO with EmployeeLevelID 1, VP with EmployeeLevelID 2, Head with EmployeeLevelID 3, and RegularEmployee with EmployeeLevelID 4), and I also have EmployeeDepartmentID as well, which corresponds to the departments of each employee. Each employee has their own department. Basically, what I'm trying to achieve here is if the person logged in is BOTH a VP (EmployeeLevelID 2) and has a Department with EmployeeDepartmentID 1, it will show all the employees with EmployeeDepartmentID's of 1-6
When I run this code, it works perfectly:

```
 if (((string)Session["EmployeeLevelID"] == "2"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query1, con))
                {

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", Session["EmployeeID"].ToString());

                    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        lvEmployees.DataSource = dr;
                        lvEmployees.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
```

But when I run this, no employees start to show: (Once I start to include EmployeeDepartmentID, employees just disappear and I don't know why. :/ How do I go about this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class DEPARTMENTHEAD_ViewListOfEmployees : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

                GetEmployees1();

        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Display list of author records from the database
    /// to the list view control. 
    /// </summary>
    void GetEmployees1()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Helper.GetConnection()))
        {
            string query1 = @"SELECT EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName 
                FROM EmployeeTable WHERE EmployeeDepartmentID=2 OR EmployeeDepartmentID=3 OR EmployeeDepartmentID=4 OR EmployeeDepartmentID=5 OR EmployeeDepartmentID=6";


            con.Open();



           if ((((string)Session["EmployeeLevelID"] == "2")) && ((string)Session["EmployeeDepartmentID"] == "1"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query1, con))
                {

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", Session["EmployeeID"].ToString());

                    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        lvEmployees.DataSource = dr;
                        lvEmployees.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }





}
```

Comment: Please add a breakpoint on `if ((((string)Session["EmployeeLevelID"] == "2")) && ((string)Session["EmployeeDepartmentID"] == "1"))` wen you hit the breakpoint, please check the value of `Session["EmployeeLevelID"]` in the `Immediate Window`. Also please check the value of `Session["EmployeeDepartmentID"]`. Also `Session["EmployeeLevelID"].GetType()` and  `Session["EmployeeDepartmentID"].GetType()`. Please update your question with each of those values.

Comment: `string query1 = @"SELECT EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName 
                FROM EmployeeTable WHERE EmployeeDepartmentID=2 OR EmployeeDepartmentID=3 OR EmployeeDepartmentID=4 OR EmployeeDepartmentID=5 OR EmployeeDepartmentID=6";` That code can be simplified to `string query1 = @"SELECT EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName 
                FROM EmployeeTable WHERE EmployeeDepartmentID IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)";`

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", Session["EmployeeID"].ToString());` Why are you passing that when your query does not use that parameter?

Answer (score -1):

Please change your code like following way.

Step 1: Please create one stored procedure for fetch the data from SQL.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetEmployee

@EmployeeID INT

AS BEGIN

SELECT EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName 
FROM EmployeeTable WHERE 
EmployeeDepartmentID=2 OR EmployeeDepartmentID=3 OR 
EmployeeDepartmentID=4 OR EmployeeDepartmentID=5 OR 
EmployeeDepartmentID=6
AND EmployeeID=@EmployeeID

END
```

Step 2: Change your code like following way.

```
 public void GetEmployees1()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Helper.GetConnection()))
        {

            con.Open();

            if (Session["EmployeeLevelID"].ToString() == "2" && Session["EmployeeDepartmentID"].ToString() == "1")
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetEmployee", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", Session["EmployeeID"].ToString());
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                lvEmployees.DataSource = ds;
                lvEmployees.DataBind();

            }

            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If need to change the logic later, we can do the same with out disturb front end.(Only if parameter is not changing.) I am suggesting do all coding using stored procedure.

Comment: Stored procedure is not a Solution. I have changed the .net code also. I have corrected the code as per my style. It's may be help him.